# Can I know whether the input augment is reference(&) or rvalue reference(&&)?

Tags: c++

I am learning c++.
 Sometime, I would like to know whether the "element" as input to the function below is reference(=&) or rvalue reference(=&&) during debugging.

```
// This is an example code to explain my question simply.
template <typename Element>
void add_container_side(Element&& element) {
    static std::vector vec;
    vec.push_back(std::forward<Element>(element));
}
```

Do I have a way to know whether the "element" is reference(=&) or rvalue reference(=&&) only by tracing this function with debugger? In other words, can I know it without reading stacks of debugger before this function? My real code has deep stacks. I am using CDT of eclipse.

Thank you very much.

Comment: does the debugger show what type `Element` was deduced to ?  Deduction of `T &` means lvalue reference, otherwise rvalue reference

Comment: @M.M : thank you for telling me it. I did not know it. I confirm it. When I put lvalue to the my code, it has & mark and rvalue without any mark as you say. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The debugger should show what the template parameter `Element` was deduced to:

- `T &` means the argument was an lvalue.
- `T` means the argument was a prvalue.
- `T &&` means the argument was an xvalue.